logger is creating unwanted character
i have created logger following way. not sure what is wrong with logger.
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                            format=r'[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s',
                            datefmt="%H:%M:%S",
                            handlers=[
                                logging.FileHandler(logfile, 'w'),
                                console_handler
                            ])
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('TOOL')
        return self.logger

============================
if i add format and datefmt it will add junk character.
if i remove format and datefmt it will not add junk character, not sure
